# Netcat not working as expected when executed remotely in a non interactive shell

Tags: ssh, netcat

I have observed many unexpected behaviour when trying to start netcat in listen mode remotely.
1. When following command is used :

```
ssh root@198.18.40.13 'nc -l -k 80 &'
```

I observed that the first tcp connection to this listener from any client fails. When trying to establish connection, the listener issues a FIN packet and closes the connection. But when trying to connect once more, connection gets established.
I noted some problem with the file descriptors and when I used -d option while starting the netcat :

```
ssh root@198.18.40.13 'nc -d -l -k 80 &'
```

, this problem gets solved. But I couldn't understand what exactly causes this issue. My question is why does netcat behave differently when executed remotely using ssh.

2. Another problem I noted is the verbal mode doesn't work.

   ssh root@198.18.40.13 'nc -l -v -k 80 &'

This doesn't even start netcat when -v is used.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ending the command with &, supply the `-f` flag to ssh. Netcat is dying of SIGPIPE when it writes output and sshd is gone.  Alternatively, if you don't want to send output back over ssh, you can also redirect netcat's output to a file before putting it in the background `... > /tmp/nc.log &`.

Comment: But I noted that only the first connection has problem. The second time when I try to connect through TCP it establishes the connection. I found this behaviour a little weird.

Comment: Maybe you are behind an interception ("transparent") proxy and some middlebox is terminating your TCP connection, or something else is listening on port 80?  But your `nc` process is dying.  An easier way to reproduce the problem is to run `nc -l -k 8888 |& true`.  You'll see that as soon as `nc` attempts to write to the pipe, it dies.  Then run `nc -v -l -k 8888 |& true` and it will die immediately because the debugging chatter will go to the pipe and cause a SIGPIPE.